# Quotient of estimators

Tags: st.statistics, estimation-theory, moments

Say $A$ is a set of a finite number of samples, and $\hat{\mu}_A$ and $\hat{\sigma}_A$ are unbiased estimators (computed over $A$) of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ which are some distinct population statistics. They need not be the mean and standard deviation, although the symbols imply so.

My goal is to estimate $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$.

0. I believe I cannot declare $\frac{\hat{\mu}_A}{\hat{\sigma}_A}$ an unbiased estimator, since the numerator and the denominator are correlated. Even if the numerator and denominator are measured from two independent sets of samples, i.e. $\frac{\hat{\mu}_A}{\hat{\sigma}_B}$, now the problem is that, in general, $\frac{1}{\hat{\sigma}_B}$ is not an unbiased estimator of $\frac{1}{\sigma}$. I can perhaps show one or both of the following:
1. If the second-order statistics of both  $\hat{\mu}_A$ and ${\hat{\sigma}_A}$ grow at a slower rate compared to their first-order statistics, then $\frac{\hat{\mu}_A}{\hat{\sigma}_A}$ is an asymptotically unbiased estimator.
2. If the second-order statistics of only ${\hat{\sigma}_B}$ grows at a slower rate compared to its first-order statistics, then $\frac{\hat{\mu}_A}{\hat{\sigma}_B}$ is an asymptotically unbiased estimator. The samples in $A$ and $B$ are independently sampled.

Are all three statements true? Should I also require that all statistics higher than the second-order statistics should grow at a slower rate compared to the first-order statistics?

Comment: Instead of "a finite number of samples" you ought to say "a finite sample." The reason one speaks of the "size" of  "sample", and the reason why one calls a "two-sample t-test" a "two-sample t-test" are that a _sample_ consists of a number of (typically) independent observations.

Comment: You say you cannot declare $\hat\mu_A/\hat\sigma_A$ unbiased because the numerator and denominator are correlated. In one of the most frequently considered situations, the sample mean and the sample standard deviation are NOT correlated, despite both being based on the same sample (and notice that I am using the word "sample" correctly, to refer to a number of observations rather than to each observation separately. $ \qquad$

Comment: Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are uncorrelated (not necessarily independent) and have expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (but are not necessarily identically distributed). Let $\overline X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n.$ Then $\operatorname{cov}\big( \, \overline X,\, X_i-\overline X\, \big)=0.$ So what is correlated and what is not correlated is not only a matter of whether they're based on the same sample.

Comment: I can only guess what you mean by first- and second-order statistics. I suspect you may mean the means and variances of the estimators. But I wouldn't use the word "statistic" to refer to those. Maybe that's physicists' language?